# SWT/AWT integration: alternatives to or further development of Albireo

Tags: swt, awt, swt-awt, albireo

There is quite a lot of [manual work needed to improve SWT/Swing integration when using SWT_AWT bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html#sec-adding-to-bridge). [Albireo](http://www.eclipse.org/albireo/) project was intended to fix this, but it's now archived. Is there any alternative? Or is it developed further unofficially?

Comment: You definitely have some reason, but I have to ask. Why do you want to integrate Swing and SWT?

Comment: I need to render some things related to our domain in an Eclipse RCP application. The rendering component is written in Swing (for a different application) and I can't rewrite it (it is far too big).

Comment: After some google search I'm affraid you'll have to do it by SWT_AWT bridge..